# How can remove the 'ModuleNotFound' error while my AppOpener module is installed?

Tags: python-3.x

I had installed the AppOpener module but the IDLE is saying module not found and stops the program. How can I solve the problem?

I had typed the following command -
from AppOpener import open
app = input('Tell the app to be opened: ')
open(app)
but the result was very unexpected -
(Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\Python Projects (Advanced)\Jarvis AppOpener.py", line 1, in 
from AppOpener import open
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'AppOpener')
I was trying to open apllication but the programmed stopped without even asking the app.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed **AppOpener** like:

```
pip install AppOpener
```

and if the issue still exists, try running the program in **python shell in cmd**

Comment: it works in cmd, but is there any way to make it work in idle?

Comment: What IDLE are you using?